# Book in which a young girl finds a dragon egg

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read this book in an elementary school second grade class, and they clamored for it!

The young girl is unusual; found a large (dragon) egg, protected it and can ride the young dragon, teaching it to be helpful. When the dragon leaves to find its destiny (my words), the girl is charged with raising a clutch of other baby dragons. The final picture, as I recall, is of the older dragon flying away, and the young child watching a teeming group of various creatures in a body of water.

Comment: The first bit of this sounds like *Dragonflight* but the final picture is more like *Dragondrums* -- both part of the Dragonriders of Pern series -- but this doesn't quite match.

Comment: @HCBeaudet - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, you mentioned a "final picture," so did the book feature illustrations, or were you speaking figuratively? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Well, in *Dragonflight* one can hardly say that Lessa "found" the egg.  And *Dragondrums* is part of the *Harper Hall of Pern* subseries, with a completely different cast of characters and dragons that can't be ridden.

Comment: @DavidW The Harper Hall series does have dragons that can be ridden but the hero, Menolly, actually is more involved with the fire lizards that are their (apparent) progenitors. There is overlap between the characters, as well - Lessa and Robinton appear in both, for instance, and Menolly attends a Hatching at Benden.

Comment: @tsc_chazz Ah, I guess it's been too long.  I only really remember Menolly and the fire lizards.  But I don't remember Menolly raising a dragon, just fire lizards?

Comment: @DavidW you are correct, she doesn't raise a dragon, though the Pern dragons do play a substantial role in the Harperhall series - and she does ride on a couple of them as passenger. No, she has her hands full with 9 fire lizards of her own, plus helping Robinton, Sebell, and Lord Groghe with theirs.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me the Pern books would be in an elementary school curriculum. Some of them have rather adult themes.